# SQL server 2008 fast retrieval

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to process and retrieve large Data sets fast and accurate. Performance is a must. I've tried many techniques but it wasn't fast enough...

Any ideas??

Edit: Similar to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

Comment: Similar to what??  Did you forget to add a link?

Comment: just edited the question

Comment: sorry i forgot to paste the link

Comment: What does 'accurate' performance mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SET ROW COUNT` would only limit the rows being returned and not improve performance, you could achieve the same results by using the `TOP` keyword in your queries.

Since you are dealing with large quantities of data and are trying to improve performance you could try some of the following techniques:

- Add indexes to columns referenced in your queries.
- Look at the execution plan of your queries and see the most expensive operations.
- Use stored procedures, you will get the benefits of the execution plan as well as caching if the database engines detects queries with the same parameters.
- Partition the tables, this could improve performance by splitting large quantities of data up into multiple tables based upon date ranges.
- Run the database tuning wizard.

Comment: I guess i have to seriously start tracking down the expensive operations, i definitly can do that, thanx for the tips :)

Comment: @userTepmo you're welcome. You can include the execution plan in SQL Server Management Studio and take a look at that.